# Create installation (.msi) from .exe file

Tags: installation, executable, exe, windows-installer

I have Java application, export to runnable .jar and then convert that .jar file to .exe file.
I need to create installation for windows ( .msi file ). Can anybody suggest me good program ( easy add icon and other settings  ) for that task ?

Comment: To convert an installer exe into an msi file?  To create an installer that installs the exe file?  Please be specific.

Comment: Do you have the source file or just the compiled?

Comment: I edited my question to be clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a .msi file for a Java program ? (eclipse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159737/how-can-i-create-a-msi-file-for-a-java-program-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best program I know for that is Installshield, is not the only program but you can custom everything.

If you would like to research a little bit you have a list here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Answer (score 5):

Taken literally there is no such thing as an EXE to MSI 'converter'.   What you are probably trying to ask for are repackagers.

[Repackaging Applications For Distribution](http://www.appdeploy.com/articles/repack.asp)

Now that you've revised your question, you don't need to repack an existing EXE based installer, you just need to create an installer.  This is an exact duplicate of

[How can I create a .msi file for a Java program ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159737/how-can-i-create-a-msi-file-for-a-java-program-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you this website: [EXE to MSI Repackaging Knowledge Base](http://www.exe-to-msi.com). I has few articles that explain how to repackage EXE to MSI.

Comment: This is not a free solution

Answer (score 0):

Not a converter, but you may want to take a look at [**Stall**](https://github.com/jamesqo/Stall). It's an OSS project that lets you install your app via the command line, without having to configure anything.

**Disclaimer:** I wrote it. Please enjoy!